# Como mudar a build gradle para um versão anterior ( android studio )?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle

Estou criando um projeto que roda na versão do android studio 3.1,  e eu  tenho  esta  versão antiga do android studio  mas a build gradle  esta atualizada e não consigo  fazer meus códigos rodarem não quero mudar meus códigos e nem adaptar só quero voltar a versão antiga alguém pode me ajudar ? 
já tentei desista lar e instalar de novo e mesmo assim não muda nada no  build.gradle .

> como esta agora

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.t_gamer.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

> como quero que fique

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.t_gamer.deepcooeesite"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
```

Comment: Para alterar a versão do `gradle`, você teve modificar o arquivo `~/projeto/build.gradle`

Comment: sim mas não sei como modifica